# Probability of Success in Double Choice

Tags: probability

Among the $20$ shooters, $4$ shooters are champions, $10$ are average shooters, and $6$ shooters are beginners. The chance of hitting a target for a champion is $0.9$, for an average shooter - $0.7$, for a beginner - $0.5$. At random $2$ shooters are chosen. Find the probability that each of them will hit the target.

It is obvious for me, than the probability that the first chosen shooter to hit the target is equal to $P(first) = 0.9 \cdot \frac{4}{20}+ 0.7 \cdot \frac{10}{20}+ 0.5 \cdot \frac {6}{20} = 0.68$.

Further I want to find the probability that the second chosen shooter to hit the target and the final answer will be: $P(first \ and \ second) = P(first) \cdot P(second)$

However, I have some doubts about how to calculate the second probability, because it is necessary somehow to take into account the initial proportion of shooter's classes in the subsequent selection from the remaining $19$ people.

My guess is to calculate the second probability like this:

$P(second) = (0.9 \cdot \frac{4}{19} \cdot \frac{10+6}{20} + 0.9 \cdot \frac{3}{19} \cdot \frac{4}{20} )+ (0.7 \cdot \frac{10}{19} \cdot \frac {4+6}{20} + 0.7 \cdot \frac{9}{19} \cdot \frac {10}{20}) + (0.5 \cdot \frac {6}{19} \cdot \frac{4+10}{20} + 0.5 \cdot \frac {5}{19} \cdot \frac{6}{20})$

Is this method correct?

Comment: The two events, "first" and "second" are not independent.  If the first misses that is evidence (not proof) that the first was a beginner, which increases the probability that the second is a good shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate the probability of a hit for the second shooter independently of the outcome for the first. So you may just want to find the probability of two hits for six possible combinations of two shooters from Champion (C), Average (A) and Beginner (B).

Probability that both are champions $  \displaystyle \small P(C, C) = \frac{4}{20}  \cdot \frac{3}{19} = \frac{12}{380}$

Probability of two hits (say event $H$) given both are champions is $ \small P(H \mid C, C) = 0.9^2 = 0.81$

Probability that one is a champion and one is average  $ \displaystyle \small P(C, A) = \frac{4}{20} \cdot \frac{10}{19} + \frac{10}{20} \cdot \frac{4}{19} = \frac{80}{380}$

$ \small P(H \mid C, A) = 0.9 \times 0.7 = 0.63$

Please calculate the rest of them similarly and finally by the law of total probability,

$ \small P(H) = P(C, C) \cdot P(H \mid C, C) + P(A, A) \cdot P(H \mid A, A) + P(B, B) \cdot P(H \mid B, B) + P(C, A) \cdot P(H \mid C, A) + P(C, B) \cdot P(H \mid C, B) + P(A, B) \cdot P(H \mid A, B)$